# Authentication failed for git repository in Jeniks (linux)

Tags: linux, git, ssh, jenkins

I'm doing Jenkins config for first time. All the configuration about git, ssh, etc.  is made in a linux server by console (VM). I've created a user and password for git and added the public key to the bitbucket host, I have connected by command line in linux to bitbucket and everything was fine. But when I try to connect to the remote repo in Jenkins Job Config, I get this error:
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h 'repo' HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'repo'

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the private key (id_rsa or similar) On the box? What linux user is Jenkins running as? (ps -ef | grep jenkins)

Comment: id_rsa is in the /.ssh directory of git. Also I've created a directory in jenkins (~/.ssh) and a key for it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a solution just writing the repo url as : https://:@bitbucket.org//.git

Maybe it would exist another for avoiding to express the password in the url.

Thank you @ComputerDruid and rest of comunity ;)